# How to order a NHibernate 3.0 Linq query based on a supplied property name

Tags: .net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to order my NHibernate 3.0 Linq query dynamically, based on a column name stored in a string variable.

```
// The value of this variable can be the name of any property of Document.
string columnName = "column1";

var query = from n in Session.Query<Document>()
            where n.DocumentNumber == documentNumber
            // how to order by the value of columnName?
            select n;
```

The `orderby` keyword does accept a string (or variable) but when I execute the following:

```
var query = from n in Session.Query<Document>()
            where n.DocumentNumber == documentNumber
            orderby columnName
            select n;
```

I get this exception:

> could not execute query

```
select TOP (@p0)
  accumulate0_.Id as Id9_, 
  accumulate0_.DocumentNumber as Documen10_9_
from dbo.Documents accumulate0_
where
  accumulate0_.DocumentNumber=@p1
order by @p2 desc
```

> The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part
>     of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when
>     ordering by an expression referencing a column name.

I know there's the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) which provides an overload of the `.OrderBy` extention method that accepts a string <strike>but that obviously only works in memory</strike>. It throws an exception when using NHibernate 3.0 however.

I'm trying to have the `ORDER BY` statement in the generated SQL query have the appropriate column name specified, so I need to stay in the NHibernate realm.

Using NHibernate criteria, I can order dynamically but since I'm using NHibernate Linq, I don't seem to have access to criteria features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamic LINQ works with any source, not just in memory.

That's what we are using right now.

Comment: So I guess I got that wrong then... but sadly the Dynamic LINQ OrderBy throws an exception (I don't remember which one exactly, it was a while ago) when using NHibernate 3.0, while it did work in older versions.

Comment: If you paste the exception, we might be able to help.

Comment: I don't know what happened in the meantime but I've just tried the Dynamic Linq OrderBy method, providing the column name as a string and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> but since I'm using NHibernate Linq, I
>   don't seem to have access to criteria
>   features.

Surely Session. should bring up CreateCriteria? NHibernate Linq and CreateCriteria should live quite happier together.

Not sure if is it possible using linq alone, also I don't think it is possible using QueryOver but one way may be to use CreateCriteria as you have pointed out.

```
var query = Session
    .CreateCriteria<Document>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("DocumentNumber", documentNumber))
    .AddOrder(Order.Asc("column1"))
    .List<Document>();
```

Another way would be to use HQL.